# Swift Playground does not find SpriteKit particle file

Tags: ios, swift, sprite-kit, swift-playground

I'm making a a project that has to use swift playground (.swiftpm);
It uses swiftUI for some elements but the main is on a SpriteKit Scene. My problem is that I want to use a particle and it just can't find it.

```
func moveSubmarine(newPosition : Float){
    if let bubble = SKEmitterNode(fileNamed: "Bubbles.sks") {
        submarine.addChild(bubble)
    }
    else{
        print("No particle found")
    }
    checkDepthForEvent(newPosition)
}
```

This is where I call it. And here is my project tree[image]

Comment: "I`ve tried everything". Edit your question with what you tried so people don't suggest things you already tried.

Comment: The .sks file must be in the Resources folder of the app bundle to locate the file correctly. In the Mac version of Swift Playgrounds, adding a .sks file to the playground creates a Resources folder for the playground and places the .sks file in the folder. I'm not sure what you have to do to add a Resources folder in the iPad version of Swift Playgrounds.